# How should we upgrade a state which is owned by one DL participant but has a participant list which includes more than one participant?

Tags: corda

I am looking for the correct contract upgrade process. Consider the following example:

```
    SimpleContract : Contract {
        data class State(override val owner: AbstractParty, val relevantParticipant: AbstractParty) : OwnableState {
            override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = listOf(owner, relevantParticipant)
            override fun withNewOwner(newOwner: AbstractParty): CommandAndState
            = CommandAndState(Commands.Move(), copy(owner = newOwner))
        }
    }
```

As I understand, this state is only stored in the owner's vault, but the relevantParticipant also has (in it's transaction storage) the transaction  where the SimpleContract.State is one of the outputs. If the owner were to (authorize and) initiate the upgrade, the flow fails as the relevantParticipant does not have the authorized contract upgrade for it. What is the right approach here?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is for the owner to send the `StateRef` to the `relevantParticipant`. The `relevantParticipant` can then retrieve the `StateAndRef` using `ServiceHub.loadState`, and choose to authorise the contract upgrade using `ContractUpgradeFlow.Authorise`.

This is better than sending the `StateAndRef` directly, since the `relevantParticipant` can then verify that the state being sent hasn't been tampered with (since they retrieve the actual state from their storage, not the counterparty's).